# Setup URL for the page where URL changes every time automatically and the old URL gets invalid

Tags: html, web, url

My Client want to add this functionality to his website that the URL changes every time automatically and the old URL gets Invalid
This is important that the URL gets changed every time automatically.
Is it possible?

I tried searching on the internet but did'nt find any solution for this.

Comment: Do you need to add that feature or fix it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JRichardsz We need to add that feature